# Setting a countdown that does something in the end

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I'm trying to set a countdown that will do something before and after, 
I'm using the code from this site: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

I have this code, but I don't know how to:

1. set the end time;
2. do something before and after the timer is done;
3. schedule the clock automatically.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
     };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

//var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var schedule = [
    ['May 10 2020', 'May 10 2020']              
];
//initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
// iterate over each element in the schedule
for(var i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
    var startDate = schedule[i][0];
    var endDate = schedule[i][1];

    // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
    var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
    var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
    var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

    // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
    if(endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs ){
        initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate);
    }
}
```

Could you please advise me?

Comment: Use something like this ` var deadline = 'December 31 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0200';` for setting endtime.

Comment: i just realized what was a mistake, i can now set the endtime.